# How to periodically process some input using Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I wonder if there is a way to make Camel do what I need which is as follows:

"Periodically read data from some source (let's say a file), do some processing on it and write it to some other place"

I figured out how to do all that minus the "periodically" part. I know how to trigger a route using Quartz or Timer. But when I use those the  part is already taken so I can't change the body anymore.

Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can kick it off with timer/quartz and then use either a [content enricher](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) or a [polling consumer](http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html)

```
//using timer/pollEnrich to populate the body with the polling results
from("timer://foo?period=5000")
    .pollEnrich("file:inbox")
    .to("file:outbout");

//using time/polling consumer bean for more flexibility and multiple polling
from("timer://foo?period=5000")
    .bean(myPollingConsumerBean, "doIt");

public static class MyPollingConsumerBean {
...
    public void doIt() {
      while (true) {
        String msg = consumer.receiveBody("file:inbox", 3000, String.class);
        if (msg == null) {
            break;
        }
        producer.sendBody("file:outbox", msg);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use scheduled route policy as well
http://camel.apache.org/scheduledroutepolicy.html